# How does the state updates of objects in React work accurately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am learning React, and trying to wrap my head around the syntax, and concepts.    From the tutorials of React it is mentioned:

> **State Updates May Be Asynchronous**
>
> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

My question is, if the this.state is not updated at all times, can we rely on it to show the right information?  If my understanding is correct, React will update this state in batches for performance reasons, but does it affect the accuracy of the application?  How does React create these batches and when do they get applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React will render component with updated state as soon as it is reasonable - for example in event handlers you are able to change state of multiple components, however it is not reasonable to render them with new state separately - instead React will batch updates and render components after event handler finishes.

In correctly written application delay between update and render will be unnoticeable for user. From developer perspective asynchronous updates may introduce hard-to-find bugs (using Redux where every state update is based on previous state should solve most of them; this is of course possible also in pure React by using `setState()` with callback).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I see, so it does a logical grouping, and if you write code in a certain way it wont cause problems.  Like you mentioned in event handlers, so you cannot update the state of some object, and then use that state for changing something else in the same handler?  You mentioned Redux, is it ideal to include another library for this, or to do it using callbacks?

Comment: Keep in mind that you know new state - you are setting it (just don't access it by `this.state`). Also remember that you can pass callback as second argument to `setState()` which will be called after state update. However better option is to use `componentDidUpdate` method of component.

Redux forces specific architecture - check if it fits your needs. Personally I think it is good for complex SPA but over-complicated for simple applications.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, they were really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

React uses state to help manage each piece of component with javascript. Since state can always change it makes it really flexible. One downside is that since it is flexible it can be hard to manage the state when there are multiple objects. It is ideal to keep components in manageable pieces so that you can locate when a state is not behaving as expected.

To prevent data from mutating unexpectedly, tools/concept such as ImmutableJs or Redux have been combined with React to make managing tools more efficent.

Redux controls/organizes where pieces of state changes through a one-directional flow. http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html

ImmutableJs uses persistent immutable data structures which locks state to prevent unexpected changes. https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/

Comment: Thank you, I will look into these libraries as well.

Answer (score 1):

State being asynchronous does not mean that you can't rely on it, but you should be careful how and when you are using the information you are keeping there.

For example:

```js
this.setState({charCount: 5});
console.log(this.state.charCount) // may not be 5 as setState is asynchronous
```

On the other hand you can use callback to be sure that you got a correct value:

```js
this.setState({charCount: 5}, () => { console.log(this.state.charCount) });
```

General practice is that you should try to minimize the use of state and only use it, when changes are needed on user interface. If you need to process or manipulate data without UI changes try to avoid using state and use for example this practice: [Lifting State Up](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: Thank you I will look into the suggested article.